# Recoger los datos de un Foreach en PHP con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Primeramente genero una tabla con foreach en php para mostrar los datos de mis alumnos.

```
<div class="col col-md-12">
<h2>Alumnos de 1º ESO</h2>        
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_alumnos">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>E-Mail</th>
    <th>Curso</th>
    <th>Fecha Registro</th>
    <th>Opciones</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php
    foreach($primer as $item) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td name='id' id='".$item->id."'>".$item->id."</td>";
        echo "<td name='nombre' id='".$item->nombre."'>".$item->nombre."</td>";
        echo "<td name='apellido' id='".$item->apellido."'>".$item->apellido."</td>";
        echo "<td name='email' id='".$item->email."'>".$item->email."</td>";
        echo "<td name='curso' id='".$item->curso."'>".$item->curso."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item->fecha_registro."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='".base_url()."alumno/".$item->id."/asdf' class='btn btn-warning'><span class='fa fa-eye'></span></a>";
        echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' name='edit' id='edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' onClick='selectedAlumno()'><span class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></span></button>";            
        echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger' value='".$item->id."' name='del'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></button></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

Cada uno con su boton de editar que llama a la siguiente function: `onClick='selectedAlumno()'` que corresponde a la siguiente imagen:

```
//Función para pasar los parametros a nuestra ventana modal
function selectedAlumno() {


  $('#table_alumnos').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.find('td[name=id]').attr('id');
    var nombre = $this.find('td[name=nombre]').attr('id');
    var apellido = $this.find('td[name=apellido]').attr('id');
    var email = $this.find('td[name=email]').attr('id');
    var curso = $this.find('td[name=curso]').attr('id');

    $('#mid').val(id);
    $('#mnombre').val(nombre);
    $('#mapellido').val(apellido);
    $('#memail').val(email);
    $('#mcurso').val(curso);
  });

}
```

En el Script tomo los datos de cada ID por su NAME y los asigno a su ventana modal con: `$('#mid').val(id);`

Ventana Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Formulario de edición: Exámenes <span class='fa fa-sign-in'></span></h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-control" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'Alumnos_listado/form_alumnos_validacion_editar' ?>">
                        <div>
                        <label>URL actual</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" value="<?php echo base_url(uri_string()) ?>">
                        <br>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <label>ID Alumno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mid" id="mid" readonly>
                        <br>
                        </div>
                        <label>Nombre del Alumno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mnombre" id="mnombre" placeholder="">
                        <br>
                        <label>Apellido del Alumno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mapellido" id="mapellido" placeholder="">
                        <br>
                        <label>E-Mail del Alumno</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="memail" id="memail" placeholder="">
                        <br>
                        <label class="mr-sm-2">Curso</label>
                        <select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="mcurso" id="mcurso"> 
                          <option disabled selected value>Seleccione un curso</option>
                          <option value="1ESO">1º ESO</option>
                          <option value="2ESO">2º ESO</option>
                          <option value="3ESO">3º ESO</option>
                          <option value="4ESO">4º ESO</option>
                        </select>
                        <br><br>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mbtnCerrarModal">Cerrar <span class='fa fa-close'></span></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Actualizar <span class='fa fa-refresh'></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                        if($this->session->flashdata('error_message') != '') {
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>";
                            echo $this->session->flashdata('error_message');
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                        if($this->session->flashdata('success_message') != '') {
                            echo "<div class='alert alert-success'>";
                            echo $this->session->flashdata('success_message');
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Si edito el primer alumno de la tabla se abre el modal y muestra perfectamente todos sus datos, pero al clicar en editar los demás alumnos, siempre coge el primer alumno de la tabla.

¿Como podría controlarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero has de tener en cuenta que las ids de los elementos html deberían ser únicas, es decir dos elementos html no deben tener la misma id. Tu código genera que una tabla donde las id se repiten en cada fila, y como utilizas como selector de javascript la id, javascript lo que hace es seleccionar el primero que encuentra con esa id.

Deberias modificar el codigo que genera el html para que no produzca la misma id para dos elementos.

Ademas no es necesario que utilizes la función `.click()` de jQuery, ya que el atributo `onClick` de html ya se encarga de hacer una acción equivalente.

Una forma sencilla de determinar el elemento que ha sido presionado es simplemente pasar el objeto en el atributo `onClick`.

html:

```
onClick='selectedAlumno(this)'
```

Después en javascript puedes coger ese objeto i desde el obtener los valores que necesitas, una opción puede ser.

javascript:

```
function selectedAlumno(boton) {

  var celdas = $(boton).closest('tr').find('td');

  var id = celdas.eq(0).text();
  var nombre = celdas.eq(1).text();
  var apellido = celdas.eq(2).text();
  var email = celdas.eq(3).text();
  var curso = celdas.eq(4).text();

  $('#mid').val(id);
  $('#mnombre').val(nombre);
  $('#mapellido').val(apellido);
  $('#memail').val(email);
  $('#mcurso').val(curso);

}
```

Este código coge el texto de cada celda, si prefieres un método similar al que tienes, donde utilizas un atributo que contiene la información, ten en cuenta que `html5` permite la utilización de atributos propios.

La celda de nombre podría ser

```
<td data-nombre="Juan">Juan</td>
```

y acceder al valor con

```
selectorDeLacelda.attr('data-nombre');
```